# Attach 'Enter key press' to trigger events in Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

[image]

I'm learning Bash Script and now want to make a simple console game just using pure Bash without external libraries. But I'm just wondering how to make buttons and attach some `key presses` like the `Enter` key for users to make some app's logic events.

Would anyone suggest or give me some resources to achieve this?

Comment: Probably this is an interesting post for you: [How do I create a terminal based gui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285777/how-do-i-create-a-terminal-based-gui)

Comment: @thanasisp Thanks for the suggestion! However, I don't want to use external libraries such `dialog` , etc. Is any way to draw the simple GUI just using pure Bash?

Comment: you may need `dialog`: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-use-ncurses-widgets-in-shell-scripts-on-linux

Comment: Your question is effectively "I want to do something complicated but I want to use a completely inappropriate language and I don't want to use any of the tools which might make it feasible".  You should re-think your goals and/or your implementation plans.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do a GUI in bash. You can do menu-based interactions though: get familiar with the `select` command.

Here's an example:

```bsh
PS3='What do you want to do [1-4]> '
select choice in "Join" "Sign In" "Sign Out" "Exit"; do
    case $choice in 
        Join)
            join_command
            break ;;
        "Sign In")
            sign_in_command
            break ;;
        "Sign Out")
            sign_out_command
            break ;;
        Exit)
            echo "kthxbye"
            exit ;;
    esac
done
```

which looks like

```
1) Join
2) Sign In
3) Sign Out
4) Exit
What do you want to do [1-4]>
```